# Backup table regulary mysql

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sql-server, sqlite

I have a table called **tbl_a** that has just three columns (*id, name, email*). I want to create a backup of this table every hour. **tbl_a_backup** would be the name of my backup table.

**The logic of insertion:**

If the *id* is not in **tbl_a_backup**, insert it. If the *id* is already there, replace the row in the backup table, with the row from the original table **tbl_a**. I want to replace the row from the backup table, only if the row from the original table is different now, if it's the same row, no need for replace (if it helps).

I am currently doing this with python, but I'm looking for an SQL solution, if it's possible. I'm sure that the query time would be very low, compared to the entire python script. I don't have a lot of rows now, but once I get to 100k, I'm sure there would be a speed difference.

Comment: Looking at the description of your backup logic: How is the result different from making a copy? Which would be much faster.

Comment: I don't need a copy, because rows can be deleted from the original table, but I still want to keep them in my backup table.

Comment: So, what would be the recovery strategy then? Restore everything with all the rows that have been deleted, most likely for a reason?

Comment: so, I would run a script every hour that will save the tbl_a table, into a different table. Stuff can be deleted from tbl_a because it will still remain in the tbl_a_backup. That's my idea, to make a full backup of a table, even though that table will be changed, or even get empty at some point.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to create job. Please read this:

[10 Ways to Automatically & Manually Backup MySQL Database](http://www.noupe.com/development/10-ways-to-automatically-manually-backup-mysql-database.html)
[5.7.2 Online Backup](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-mysql-enterprise-backup-online-backup.html)
[How to back up MySQL databases using cron jobs](https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/mysql/mysql-database-backups-using-cron-jobs)